# string from list items after sortableJS has been applied

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I am tring to get a string from a list after it has been sorted using jquery ui sortable 
Using a simple list ( without sorting)

```
    <ul id = "description">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
```

and applying

```
$('#description').text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
```

I get: one two three
However if I make the list sortable and move items around, and using

```
function getOrder() {
            alert($("#description").html());//gives a correct html ul
            alert($("#description").text());// no spaces between words
            var ans = $('#description').text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
                alert("You got " + ans)
};
```

The output changes to three twoone or threetwoone - spacing messed up. `$("description").html()`
shows that the html is correct ( style="" gets added to the li tag for some reason) , but `$('#description').text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");` does not give a properly spaced string.
Why does sorting change the behaviour and what can I do to resolve this? Appreciate any response please

Comment: Why does your title say SortableJS if you are using jQuery-UI Sortable? They are two completely different libraries.

Comment: Shows how much I know. A previous post was edited and that change suggested. Still appreciate some help though.

Comment: Ok I answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text, I would create a toString function:

```js
function toString(element) {
    var children = element.children;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        str += (!i ? '' : ' ') + children[i].textContent;
    }
    return str;
}
```

And then call that function with the HTMLElement (not jQuery object) of the list passed in as an argument.

This solution does not utilize jQuery, so you can use it with [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) or jQuery Sortable.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the spacing changes in the example that I gave?

Comment: Probably because the newline or return carriage were removed after you sorted

Answer (score 1):

```
$.map( $('li'), function (element) { return $(element).text() }).join(' ');
```

works to get the list items into a properly spaced string